# show all listings from a specific user

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, authentication, devise

I am trying to create a page within my application that shows all listings from a specific user. I am using Devise gem for my users. i do not need/want authentication, therefore the page should be open the the general public. I have already created a "Seller" page where a seller can manage their own listings. so how can I create a link on each listing on my homepage that connects the

```
<p><%= "Sold by #{listing.user.name}" %></p>
```

the new show page for that user? thanks!

my listings_controller:

```
class ListingsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_listing, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_filter :authenticate_user!, only: [:seller, :new, :create, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_filter :check_user, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]

  def seller
    @listings = Listing.where(user: current_user).order("created_at DESC")
  end

  # GET /listings
  # GET /listings.json
  def index
    if params[:category].blank?
      @listings = Listing.all.order("created_at DESC").paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 16)
    else
      @category_id = Category.find_by(name: params[:category]).id
      @listings = Listing.where(category_id: @category_id).order("created_at DESC").paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 16)
    end
  end

  # GET /listings/1
  # GET /listings/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /listings/new
  def new
    @listing = Listing.new
  end

  # GET /listings/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /listings
  # POST /listings.json
  def create
    @listing = Listing.new(listing_params)
    @listing.user_id = current_user.id

    if current_user.recipient.blank?
      Stripe.api_key = ENV["STRIPE_API_KEY"]
      token = params[:stripeToken]

      recipient = Stripe::Recipient.create(
        :name => current_user.name,
        :type => "individual",
        :bank_account => token
        )


    current_user.recipient = recipient.id
    current_user.save

end

    respond_to do |format|
      if @listing.save
        format.html { redirect_to @listing, notice: 'Listing was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @listing }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @listing.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /listings/1
  # PATCH/PUT /listings/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @listing.update(listing_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @listing, notice: 'Listing was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @listing }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @listing.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /listings/1
  # DELETE /listings/1.json
  def destroy
    @listing.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to listings_url, notice: 'Listing was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_listing
      @listing = Listing.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def listing_params
      params.require(:listing).permit(:name, :category_id, :description, :price, :image)
    end

    def check_user
      if current_user != @listing.user
        redirect_to root_url, alert: "Sorry, this listing belongs to someone else"
      end
    end  
end
```

my current routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  mount RailsAdmin::Engine => '/admin', as: 'rails_admin'
  resources :categories

  devise_for :users
  resources :listings do
    resources :orders, only: [:new, :create]




  end
  get 'pages/about'
  get 'pages/contact'
  get 'seller' => "listings#seller"
  get 'sales' => "orders#sales"
  get 'purchases' => "orders#purchases"

# or

  root 'listings#index'
end
```

and finally, my listing model:

```
class Listing < ActiveRecord::Base
  if Rails.env.development?
        has_attached_file :image, :styles => { :medium => "200x", :thumb => "100x100>" }, :default_url => "404.jpg"
  else
        has_attached_file :image, :styles => { :medium => "200x", :thumb => "100x100>" }, :default_url => "404.jpg",
                    :storage => :dropbox,
                    :dropbox_credentials => Rails.root.join("config/dropbox.yml"),
                    :path => ":style/:id_:filename"
   end              
  validates_attachment_content_type :image, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/

  validates :name, :category_id, :description, :price, presence: true
  validates :price, numericality: { greater_than: 0}
  validates_attachment_presence :image

  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :category
  has_many :orders




end
```

my index page where I want to link to the seller specific page

```
<div class="center">
  <div class="row">
    <% @listings.each do |listing| %>
      <div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="thumbnail">
       <%= link_to image_tag(listing.image.url), listing %>
        <div class="caption">
          <h3><%= listing.name %></h3>
          <p><%= number_to_currency(listing.price) %></p>
          <p><%= "Sold by #{listing.user.name}" %></p>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>

<br>

<div class="center">
  <%= will_paginate @posts, renderer: BootstrapPagination::Rails %>
</div> 

<% if user_signed_in? %>

<div class="right">
    <%= link_to new_listing_path, class: "btn btn-primary", data: { no_turbolink: true } do %>
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i> New Listing
    <% end %>
</div>    
<% end %>

<br>
```

Answer (score 0):

'User' is a model that you have created: devise only manages sessions, registrations, passwords, unlocks, and confirmations (the gem provides a controller for each one of these).

You should create your own `UsersController`, in which you can define the `show` action that you need. You should also declare a different path in your routes, or you'd have a conflict as '/users' is already used by devise. Something like

```
resources :users, only: [:show], path: 'sellers'
```

Then you can use

```
<p><%= "Sold by #{link_to listing.user.name, user_path(listing.user)}" %></p>
```